# Function declared in the header of an if statement is undefined afterwards

Tags: javascript, scope

Why is `typeof f` `"undefined"` in below example? Shoudn’t it be `"function"`?

```
var x;

if (function f(){}) {
  x = typeof f;
}

console.log(x); // "undefined"
```

Comment: Downvotes with comments would be appreciated more.Thanks.

Comment: Even `if((function f(){},console.log(typeof f),1)){}` will log `"undefined"`. The function is seemingly scoped to _nothing_. Even `if((function f(){},(function(){debugger;})(),1)){}` yields no occurrence of `f`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** My apologies on my quick response, I didn't read the question well enough.

But I do know what is happening here, since the scope of the **function** does not have access to the function declaration of `f`, `typeof f` is `undefined` and `x += typeof f` is concatenating the string "undefined" to the value of `x` (which is 1). Hence you get `1undefined` as the value of `x`

Comment: If it never went into the if statement the value of x would be 1 (and not 1undefined)

Comment: @shafeen: as per comments "since the scope of the function does not have access to the function declaration of f", i am not checking  "typeof f" inside the function,isn't it ? i am just passing the complete function as argument to the function.

Comment: No not exactly, because you are declaring the function in the if statement's check area which is its own little scope and works differently.
For example: if you had declared `f` outside the if statement and then passed it in like `if(f)` you would get a console log of `1function`, try it out.

Comment: yes that works. As per my understanding, there are no block scopes in javascript so i was thinking that functions declared inside if condition will be available outside the if but inside the function contains that if block. But thanks,got to know that functions declared in if block wont be available outside of if

Comment: @Parashuram Of course there are block scopes in JavaScript. The `let` keyword declares block-scoped variables.

Comment: @Xufox: Yes you are correct. but that will only work if we use "let" keyword. If we don't use "let" keyword, then block scope won't work and in this given example i haven't used "let" keyword but still it's creating block scope that's surprising to me.